# Can I get the date an IAM key's status (Active or Inactive) changed using boto3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I want to be able to check if an IAM access key has been inactive for 90+ days; if so, I will delete it. The problem is, I don't see a function in the [boto3 IAM client documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html) that returns the date of a key's status change. In the `list_access_keys` function, you can see a key's status (Active or Inactive) and the date the key was last used, but not the date of status change. Is there a way to get this info programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that data is available. [AccessKeyMetadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_AccessKeyMetadata.html). You can get the last time a key was used, but not when it was changed. You *might* be able to get at it via a CloudWatch event from CloudTrail, but you'd have to track it. In other words you'd have to listen to the event and if you wanted to use that later you'd need to store it somewhere.

Comment: Are you aware of any way to do this with AWS CLI? If so, I could bake that into the code.

Comment: You can't bake that into the code. You would have to add a [CloudWatch Event Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html) that fires some code (often a lambda). That could store the data somewhere (like in DynamoDB) and *then* you could query that from your CLI code.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear -- I meant to ask if I could somehow get the date a key's status changed using CLI.

Comment: No. As I mentioned, that data isn't available anywhere other than in CloudTrail. You could possibly query CloudTrail, but to do that you need to set some things up first. [Querying CloudTrail Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html)